# what method has O(log(n)) comparison

Tags: algorithm, sorting

May I ask What sorting method that uses O(log(n)) comparison (eg: arrange items in unsorted arr2 into a sorted arr1 in a sorted order)?

Comment: Binary search..

Comment: You should find this interesting to read: [Wikipedia: Number of comparisons required to sort a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list)

Answer (score 2):

None.

Several algorithms are in O(n*log(n)) though: merge sort, heap sort, quick sort, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Merge-sort sorts arrays in o(nlogn). see [Merge-sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)